# PHP selecting from Mysql database returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, select, max

My problem is that the following query of a database returns nothing, not null, nothing.

The database looks like this: The "yt" database has a table called "videos". This table has the primary key "id_int" and the varchar "video_id". There are two values in this: [Values](https://puu.sh/z1wfP/1ea044684c.png)

Here I create the connection:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "yt";
$password = "";
$dbname = "yt";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Now here is the query itself:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id_int) AS max_page FROM videos;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row;
echo $row["max_page"];
echo "Test";
```

However, the output is "Test", just to show you that the code actually gets executed. I have no idea what could be the problem, I would appreciate some help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is the problem in the query, the DB or the code? Please provide a minimal example, at it stands, it's impossible to reproduce your problems.

Comment: Connecting MySQLi: Check! Querying through MySQLi: Check. Fetching MySQLi: Failed. ;-) `mysql_*` != `mysqli_*`, and these do not mix.

Comment: your code above does not use mysqli to fetch.

Comment: Okay, that simple fix did it. Thank you so much, I just had to add an 'i'.